# Catch EOL exception in python

Tags: python, eof

I m trying to execute some code statement dynamically in Python using `exec()`

The code statement is accepted from the user input.

How do I handle the `EOF` exception that occurs when the string quotes are not closed?

For eg.

```
 >> exec('if 5 > 1: print "5 is greater)
    # of course, this will raise an exception, 
    # how do I handle this
```

How do I handle such cases, using a `try-catch`?
What `exception` should I be looking for here?

Comment: You're supposed to have a `'` at the end tho right? (I understand leaving out `"` is part of your problem to solve but the `'` should be there right?)

Comment: No! Not if the user forgets it. Its the raw input from the user!

Comment: Yea but, *sigh*.. `exec('if 5 > 1: print "5 is greater')` where the `'` at the very end is YOUR fault, not something the user inputs ain't it not? The missing `'` would not be there if you replace everything inside `exec()` with a variable called `user_string` for instance, so i'm just clarifying that that is a type-o in your question and not the actual EOL you're trying to catch because that would be close to impossible (dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

EOFError is what you are looking for

This link should help you http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html